# Accessing specific ArrayList elements, when the ArrayList changes frequently

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which stores the object `Foo`.

Let's say I want to add 10 of Objects `Foo` to the `ArrayList`, I would do something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i <10 ; i++){
    arraylist.add(new Foo());
}
```

While this solution works, the problem is, how do I access, say the ninth Foo, after the third and the fourth Foo has been deleted away from the arraylist?

I cannot simply do

```
arraylist.get(9);
```

anymore, since this would throw the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I want to be able to make the program do this dynamically, since in my case the number of Foos are not fixed, and they can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @Reimeus Is there a way to do it dynamically? Because in my program the number of Foos are not fixed.

Comment: @user2519193: That completely depends on what you're trying to do.  If you just want the last one, that's easy.  If you want to get the item at a specific index ignoring removals, you should probably set to null instead of removing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the items in specific order and you may not always remember which foo was inserted at which index, for this a `Map<Integer, Foo> is perfect.`

```
Map<Integer,Foo> map = new HashMap<Integer, Foo>();
map.put(1, new Foo());
map.put(2, new Foo());
etc
```

Per the comments, `map = TreeMap<Integer, Foo>()` might be better.

Comment: HashMap does not preserve insertion order.  TreeMap is better.

Comment: Thanks, apparantly for my needs, I shouldn't use an ArrayList to do things dynamically.

And to everyone else, sorry! I phrased my question wrongly so everyone still answered correctly technically!

Comment: Yeah that is true CPerkins, but if you iterate over the keyset you will get them in order, though not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
arraylist.get(8 - numberOFDeletedElements);
```

8 not 9 since indexing starts with 0 and 9th element in the beginning (before deletion) has index 8

or

```
arraylist.get(arraylist.size() - 2);
```

You might not need this at all. Since all the objects are same. If they are different then you might need to iterate over array and check conditions on which you want to find an element

Comment: That won't work if he deletes an element after the one he wants to access.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `equalTo()` method for your `Foo` than use `contains()` method of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned with the last element you can always just do

```
arraylist.get(arraylist.size() - 1)
```